# Introduction to Emacs Lisp function example confusion

Tags: emacs, motion, cursor-position

So I'm reading through the Emacs Lisp intro, and I come across this function used as an example for `save-excursion`:

```lisp
(message "We are %d characters into this buffer."
                   (- (point)
                      (save-excursion
                        (goto-char (point-min)) (point))))
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense in terms of why the `save-excursion` is there, what's the difference between that and this variation?

```lisp
(message "We are %d characters into this buffer."
         (point))
```

To me, it seems like all that

```
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min)) (point))
```

does is go to the beginning of the buffer and then call the `point` function...which will return zero. so then what we're effectively doing is subtracting the `point` called outside the `save-excursion` by 0. Is there some hidden functionality that I'm not catching or was that just put there for the sake of showing how `save-excursion` works?

Comment: Hmmm It seems as if the way it's implemented by the emacs intro actually makes it susceptible to narrowing based on the how point-min function works.

Comment: Yes, `(save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (point))` could just be `(point-min)` -- which makes this a pretty weird example, given that the more verbose code *uses* `(point-min)`.  I'd say it's a contrived example for demonstration purposes, but that a better example would probably be sensible.

Comment: Note also that character positions start from 1, not 0.

Comment: I agree with what others have said in comments here. Someone should consider reporting it using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Surely a better example could be used to illustrate what `save-excursion` is for.